# Batch File script to remove file that was duplicated in the Folder

Tags: batch-file, scripting, duplicates, batch-processing

Been googling on how to remove file using filename and i haven't found any that will have same scenario as mine. I was really new with this batch file scripting.

Problem:
I have 1 folder file that have lots of files and most files have duplicate of 4 to 5 other files. The only distinct between this files are the timestamp which is included in the file name.

```
sssss_1020102_201412101123
sssss_1020102_201412101124
sssss_1020102_201412101125
sssss_1020102_201412101126
```

I want to transfer all duplicate to other folder, and have the first file sssss_1020102_201412101123 remain in my folder.

```
for /r %%f in (*) do (
set filename=%%~nxf
set rootname=!filename:~0,13!
 IF "!rootname!"==""  (
     move "%source_folder%%filename%" %otherfolder% 
) ELSE ( %temp%=!filename:~0,13!
         )
```

)

I'm trying to get the first few character of the filename and assigned it to a variable but still doesn't work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (
   if not defined file[%%a_%%b] (
      rem Is the first file: define its variable
      set "file[%%a_%%b]=1"
   ) else (
      rem Not the first file: move it
      move "%%a_%%b_%%c" otherFolder
   )
)
```

**EDIT**: *Example session added*

```
C:\ dir files
 El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0895-160E

 Directorio de C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\test\files

11/12/2014  11:03 a. m.    <DIR>          .
11/12/2014  11:03 a. m.    <DIR>          ..
11/12/2014  11:01 a. m.               112 sssss_1020102_201412101123
11/12/2014  11:01 a. m.               112 sssss_1020102_201412101124
11/12/2014  11:01 a. m.               112 sssss_1020102_201412101125
11/12/2014  11:01 a. m.               112 sssss_1020102_201412101126
               4 archivos            448 bytes
               2 dirs  423,203,606,528 bytes libres

C:\ type test.bat
@echo off
setlocal

CD FILES

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D') do (
   if not defined file[%%a_%%b] (
      rem Is the first file: define its variable
      set "file[%%a_%%b]=1"
   ) else (
      rem Not the first file: move it
      ECHO move "%%a_%%b_%%c" otherFolder
   )
)

C:\ test
move "sssss_1020102_201412101124" otherFolder
move "sssss_1020102_201412101125" otherFolder
move "sssss_1020102_201412101126" otherFolder
```

Comment: You have downgrade my post question but you can't even answer my enquiry.

Comment: There is no way to know which user down _voted_ a question or answer, but I did not downvoted it. Did you tested my solution? I tested it using your example names and posted the output in the answer!

Comment: Thanks! i know now how to apply it to my actual script. I did some modification.